# Decoding and encoding in Base64 in java

Tags: base64, decode, encode

I am getting a Base64 decoded String from out side network, i ll convert the string to byte and decode it. then it will change to ASCII format. I ll store this ASCII in string send to another server.
In this case when i again encode the ASCII i am not getting the same value what i have received from out side network. But it works fine in unix system, problem is only in windows.

```
//          Base64 Encode
        String  orig = "mj5ok9qWt2v6fg3kElm8vZGeg9ZV0BqE1u2sYUQDEm8/heIdCH4ZRf7mcEcGkb8y3I24peAUBHdli8GP/MCZR/PG4NAAzd+AU3uEVM3RKTFnYwGslKQTfKgXzg+K+wkMY/0fexPkDrgVHi0vR7VXzcyx200iJYTYjJZLCwahZ7E2Cp7LW14YpCAYg8vFCp0XSZCe1luRNgq+q9xVQ88tDamAB5nGCxYZcx7X4D49HQR5vUEzIkJu2XenGQygXsGWICKv0UrVq72um0nRf0uJUa/jdMVXWtyeAsKTaVw8KTW5u745d+r7H3Fzcsl9UwL0kBfHv4WMQwz1dQ+MommXmA==";                      
        byte [] decodedvalue = Base64.decodeBase64(orig.getBytes());
        byte [] encodedvalue = Base64.encodeBase64(decodedvalue);               
        System.out.println("ORIGINAL VALUE : "+orig);
        System.out.println("ENCODED VALUE :  "+new String(encodedvalue));
        String aa =new String(decodedvalue);
        String temp = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(aa.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(" String encoded value : " +temp);
```

ORIGINAL VALUE : mj5ok9qWt2v6fg3kElm8vZGeg9ZV0BqE1u2sYUQDEm8/heIdCH4ZRf7mcEcGkb8y3I24peAUBHdli8GP/MCZR/PG4NAAzd+AU3uEVM3RKTFnYwGslKQTfKgXzg+K+wkMY/0fexPkDrgVHi0vR7VXzcyx200iJYTYjJZLCwahZ7E2Cp7LW14YpCAYg8vFCp0XSZCe1luRNgq+q9xVQ88tDamAB5nGCxYZcx7X4D49HQR5vUEzIkJu2XenGQygXsGWICKv0UrVq72um0nRf0uJUa/jdMVXWtyeAsKTaVw8KTW5u745d+r7H3Fzcsl9UwL0kBfHv4WMQwz1dQ+MommXmA==

ENCODED VALUE :  mj5ok9qWt2v6fg3kElm8vZGeg9ZV0BqE1u2sYUQDEm8/heIdCH4ZRf7mcEcGkb8y3I24peAUBHdli8GP/MCZR/PG4NAAzd+AU3uEVM3RKTFnYwGslKQTfKgXzg+K+wkMY/0fexPkDrgVHi0vR7VXzcyx200iJYTYjJZLCwahZ7E2Cp7LW14YpCAYg8vFCp0XSZCe1luRNgq+q9xVQ88tDamAB5nGCxYZcx7X4D49HQR5vUEzIkJu2XenGQygXsGWICKv0UrVq72um0nRf0uJUa/jdMVXWtyeAsKTaVw8KTW5u745d+r7H3Fzcsl9UwL0kBfHv4WMQwz1dQ+MommXmA==

String encoded value : mj5ok9qWt2v6fg3kElm8vZGeg9ZV0BqE1u2sYUQDEm8/heIdCH4ZRf7mcEcGkb8y3D+4peAUBHdli8E//MCZR/PG4NAAzd+AU3uEVM3RKTFnYwGslKQTfKgXzg+K+wkMY/0fexPkDrgVHi0vR7VXzcyx200iJYTYjJZLCwahZ7E2Cp7LW14YpCAYg8vFCj8XST+e1luRNgq+q9xVQ88tDamAB5nGCxYZcx7X4D49HQR5vUEzIkJu2XenGQygXsGWICKv0UrVq72um0nRf0uJUa/jdMVXWtyeAsKTaVw8KTW5u745d+r7H3Fzcsl9UwL0PxfHv4WMQwz1dQ+MommXmA==

Comment: when you funnel the decoded byte sequence through the `String` constructor, the byte sequence is interpreted assuming the default charset of the platform. that might differ between your unix and windows systems. moreover, if there is any byte sequence encountered which is illegal under the assumed encoding (eg. utf-8), the `String(.)` behaviour is undefined. use `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` as your string constructor. more details in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[]))

Comment: i have tried it but this time the whole message is getting wrong,String aa =new String(decodedvalue,"UTF-8");

Comment: Thanks collapsar, the issue was solved ,we added ISO-8859-1 Linux default char set.